# Nom des français habitant en dehors de la région parisienne

Tags: vocabulaire, adjectifs, france, gentilés

Parmi les gentilés que j'ai appris durant mes études pour DELFB2, il y avait (si je me souviens bien) un nom/adjectif générique qui désigne ceux qui n'habitent ni Paris, ni la banlieue de Paris ; c'est à dire tous les citoyens de la France hormis les...Parisiens.

L'ayant oublié je pose ici cette question puisque Google n'a pas donné de résultats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Une opposition *peut* être faite. Elle vaut... ce qu'elle vaut.

En France, il y a Paris et... la *province*.

Et les habitants de la province sont : des **provinciaux**. (Un provincial, une provinciale)

Attention! en fonction de qui le dit, du contexte etc. Il peut porter une certaine charge péjorative dans la mesure où, quand cette opposition est faite, c'est très souvent pour observer ou évoquer implicitement des différences en termes socio-économico-culturels qui, la plupart du temps, ne sont pas à l'avantage de la province.

<sub>NDaCOSwt : Moi... c'est *les provinciales* que j'aime beaucoup... (l'ouvrage de Blaise Pascal bien sûr!... ;-) )</sub>

Comment: Il est cependant difficile de parler de _province_ à l'égard des grandes villes telles Lyon, Marseille, etc. Le cas échéant, le caractère péjoratif sera presque toujours sous-entendu et/ou retenu.

Comment: @P.Manthe : Ha oui! Et en matière de gastronomie, il y a Lyon et la province! ;-) Et que dire du Strasbourgeois depuis que sa ville est capitale européenne ? Ha! Il doit en aller ainsi à chaque fois que l'on divise un ensemble arbitrairement et que l'on nomme les parties. Le nom de la partie à laquelle on n'appartient pas finit toujours par être entendu en mauvaise part. On observera d'ailleurs en cette occurrence de Parisien / provincial la réciprocité totale du sens péjoratif.